# PHP auto post on a group of Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have a site where people can make posts on it, and I need these posts to go straight to the feed of a group in Facebook. (I am the owner of the group)

Is it possible? What do I need? How should it work?

I found this https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk, but I don't if it is what I need, and couldn't figure out how does it work.

Comment: just go to facebook developers site it will help you, about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you'll need to:

- [Create an app](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) to connect your website to Facebook. Once the app is created, you need to get token and secret to authenticate your app with the Facebook servers.
- Capture the comments on your site.
- `POST` those comments to your Facebook group using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Additionally, to prevent spam, you may want to [authenticate your users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) with Facebook before they comment.

If you're doing this in PHP, the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php) saves you a lot of coding. To use it, your php environment must have [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar function in [my application - wootube](http://wootube.woolei.com), i added a "Share To WooTube Page & Group" button using fb.api .

After the user click the link it will automatically post to [wootube group](http://www.facebook.com/groups/wootube) and [wootube page](http://www.facebook.com/wootubes).

here is the screen shot if you want to see how it look like.
https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/383568_191076937694203_922285357_n.jpg

```
 function Promote(){
           var lnk = 'http://www.wootube.woolei.com?v=<?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>';  

        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                 //Post To WooTube Group
                 FB.api('/271691796276524/feed', 'post', { 
                 message: lnk,
                 link: lnk, 

                 }, 
                 function(response) {
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                     //alert('You have to join the group first!');

                  } else {
                     //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Group!");

                   }
                 });

                 //Post to Wootube Page
                 FB.api('/173724382762792/feed', 'post', { 
                 message: lnk,
                 link: lnk

                 }, 
                 function(response) {
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                     //alert('You have to like http://www.facebook.com/WooTubes first!');

                  } else {
                     //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Page!");

                   }
                 });

            }
            else
            {
                alert('Not logged in');
            }
        }, { scope : 'publish_stream' });


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Promote(){
           var lnk = 'http://www.wootube.woolei.com?v=<?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>';  

        FB.login(function(response)
        {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                 //Post To WooTube Group
                 FB.api('/271691796276524/feed', 'post', { 
                 message: lnk,
                 link: lnk, 

                 }, 
                 function(response) {
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                     //alert('You have to join the group first!');

                  } else {
                     //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Group!");

                   }
                 });

                 //Post to Wootube Page
                 FB.api('/173724382762792/feed', 'post', { 
                 message: lnk,
                 link: lnk

                 }, 
                 function(response) {
                   if (!response || response.error) {
                     //alert('You have to like http://www.facebook.com/WooTubes first!');

                  } else {
                     //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Page!");

                   }
                 });

            }
            else
            {
                alert('Not logged in');
            }
        }, { scope : 'publish_stream' });


      }
```